# Word Mover's Distance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, information-retrieval

I am trying to calculate the similarity of 2 texts using WMD. I have tried to use the following code in Python 3, using gensim:

```
word2vec_model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
word2vec_model.init_sims(replace=True) # normalizes vectors
distance = word2vec_model.wmdistance("string 1", "string 2")  # Compute WMD as normal.
```

However, I don't think this is returning me the right value. How should I do this in python?

Comment: Keep in mind that a smaller distance is a higher similarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please split string:

```
distance = word2vec_model.wmdistance("string 1".split(), "string 2".split())
>>> 0.4114476676950455
```

Arguments need to be list of strings.

Comment: Sometimes problems are simple! Thank you. Btw, do you know any better way of measuring if 2 texts are related or not?